# Generating passwords for the Azure Api Management Git repository

Tags: git, azure-api-management

Azure Api Management has an option to create time-bounded passwords for the integrated git repository.

As part of our VSTS release management, we want to push our changes automatically to this git repository. We don't want to create every month a new git password through the Azure portal.

The publisher portal provides [credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFbSE.png) (identifier with primary and secondary key) to generate passwords.

But I can't find any references how to use this. Could somebody give me some insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the REST api to automate this process to get credentials.

Use REST API
[Get Git UserId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/tenantaccessgit#TenantAccessGit_Get)

Then Use REST API [Generate Credentials For User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/user#User_GetSharedAccessToken) to generate the credentials for the user.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My prefered way would be with the AzureRM Cmdlets. I can use [Get-AzureRmApiManagementTenantGitAccess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.apimanagement/get-azurermapimanagementtenantgitaccess?view=azurermps-4.1.0) to get the keys. But which cmdlet corresponds to the generate credentials REST API?

Comment: We don't have that in the cmdlet yet. But you can use   `$user = Get-AzureRmApiManagementUser -Context $context | Select-Object -First 1
$subscription = Get-AzureRmApiManagementSubscription -Context $context -UserId $user.UserId | Select-Object -Last 1
$parameters = @{
"keyType"= "primary";
"expiry"= "2017-05-19T10:39:35.000Z";
}
Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ResourceType 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/users' -Action 'token' -ResourceName "$serviceName/$($user.UserId)" -ApiVersion "2016-10-10" -Parameters $parameters`

See less

Comment: Thanks for the code example! I didn't  knew the `Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction` cmdlet.